# Notating Multiple Modules in the Same Package.json File

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to package up some modules that I have been working on. I have five modules, split in to five files. Four of them are the actual outward-facing modules that I want the user to be able to install. The other one is a support module that they all need to function correctly. They are all stored in the same directory. I want to be able to specify each as a separate module in the same directory. But as far as I can tell, one can only define a single module in `package.json`.

Is there a way to specify multiple modules? If not, that means this must be a bad practice. How should I structure my module's exports to move it in to one main module?

Comment: Why not just publish them all as separate modules?  You never know how the community will use them, and they might pick one 1 out of 5 to use.

Comment: @dylants But how do I do that? The only way that I could find was to put them each in a separate directory.

Comment: Yes, each will need to live in separate directories, most likely at the same level within your directory structure.  When one requires the other, you add it to it's dependencies and `npm install` it.  Each then contains it's own source code, test code, and `package.json` file.

Comment: OK... If that's the only option, I'll have to go with it. Can you write an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that, but I think in doing this it'll help in the long run from a maintenance standpoint when you manage multiple node packages that may have separate requirements which don't directly impact the others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently there's not a supported way of having a separate `package.json` file for each module you'll be publishing within the same directory.  And really, this makes sense, as each package you deploy may have issues, feature requests, bugs, etc that need to be handled separately and don't force updates of the others.  Separating these out will allow you to focus on the maintenance of each independently, and also allow the consumers of these modules to include them separately.  A lot of larger scale projects who have started by creating something they think people will like, end up having the thing that everyone actually use be the random sub-project that was created separately.

So separate directories, and separate `package.json` files, then include dependencies within the `package.json` for each.  If you haven't already seen there's a couple good writeups to help development of node packages here:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules
- https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file
- https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects

Comment: When my sub-modules try to `require()` the main module, what path do they use? Assuming I put each (including the main one) in same-level directories, I have no idea how to reference the others. Will just the name work after I have created the package files?

Comment: If they are truly independent modules that you've deployed to npm, then you would reference them without the file path.  So if you had one called "awesome-module" you would say `require('awesome-module')`.  This means that you must first `npm publish` each module prior to requiring it for the code to work properly.  But if you document them and explain what each do, others can also benefit from your work.

Comment: Also as you publish these modules, keep very much in mind [semver](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/semver.html) notation for your package versions.

Comment: For development, you can use the `npm link` command to reference the modules locally, so you can test them before publishing. See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link